# How to access logger from model in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

The following works within the context of a request:

```
get '/' do
  logger.info 'got /'
  ...
```

But within a model,

```
class Foo
  def bar
    logger.info 'bar'
    ...
```

Sinatra throws error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'logger' for main:Object`

How to access Sinatra logger from within model?

Comment: I always redirect stdout and stderr to a log file so I can just use puts to log... If you really want to use a logger, you need to use a logger constant and put it in a class, then require it in the file you want to use it.

Comment: Are you using an ORM? Some of them, such as [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html), will let you pass in a logger instance. You'd still need to [expand  the scope to access it the way you've given above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14865988/335847), in a similar way to the one lsu_guy has given below.

Comment: @iain - Actually, for this project I am using ActiveRecord. But I am not interested in the DB log, just my own log info.

Comment: @BSeven - let us know what you end up doing. Would be curious to know.

Comment: @lsu_guy - Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried it yet. Rather than increasing complexity by creating a module, I'll probably just declare a global and set it to env['rack.logger']. Thanks for telling me how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Sinatra uses the rack logger. From readme. http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging

> Sinatra will use whatever it will find in env['rack.logger'].

You can access the logger using env['rack.logger']. Or you can implement your own app logger (seperate from Sinatra) so it saves your .log seperately and with your settings (severity level, log rotating etc). Here is a simple example for it.

```
module App
  extend self
  attr_accessor :log

  # init
  self.log = Logger.new('log/application.log', 10, 5242880)
  self.log.level = Logger::DEBUG  # could DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, UNKNOWN, WARN

  self.log.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
                              "#{severity} :: #{datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d :: %H:%M:%S')} :: #{progname} :: #{msg}\n" 
end
```

Then from your classes, use one of the following:

```
App.log.debug "some debug msg" 
App.log.info  "some info msg"
App.log.error "some error msg"
```

Comment: note that you will need to `require 'logger'` if you want that code sample to work.